# How to unset a value of a jquery variable?

Tags: jquery, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

I am trying to unset or remove a value of the jquery variable.I am updating a value to the div using the jquery. Here i show the address of the user from the latitude and longitude from api response.

Some times if the latitude and longitude value is 0 the div shows previous result.i wanted to remove the previous value and need a fresh load of the div.

Div to change the value through the jquery call.

```
<div id="wiPlayerLocation" class="datenTime"> </div>
```

The jquery i used:

```
        var wiLats = entry.data.latitude;
        var wiLons = entry.data.longitude;

        var lat = parseFloat(wiLats);
        var lng = parseFloat(wiLons);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0]) {
                 wiLatLongAddress = ' / ' + results[0].formatted_address;

                     $('#wiPlayerLocation').html("  " + wiLatLongAddress);

               }
            }
        });
```

I need to reset/unset/remove the value of the variable wiLatLongAddress or remove the data from the div.

Comment: Do you want to remove what is inside the div, like the inner html? `$("wiPlayerLocation").html("");`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

$('#wiPlayerLocation').html("  ");

in the else part of if (results[0]) condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add else and reset the value if

```
var wiLats = entry.data.latitude;
        var wiLons = entry.data.longitude;

        var lat = parseFloat(wiLats);
        var lng = parseFloat(wiLons);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0]) {
                 wiLatLongAddress = ' / ' + results[0].formatted_address;

               }
              else{
                 wiLatLongAddress  = '';
               }
               $('#wiPlayerLocation').html("  " + wiLatLongAddress);
            }
        });
```